# Simulate output with 3 cases

Tags: logic, ternary

Physically is possible to simulate such situation on a board, using electronic components. 
I got 2 inputs A and B , with 3 possible values for each one (-1,0,1). My final aim is to achieve this following truth table

```
     A |  B | result
    –1 | –1 | +1
    –1 | +1 |  0
     0 |  0 |  0
     0 | +1 | +1
    +1 | –1 |  0
    +1 |  0 | +1
    +1 | +1 | -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pseudo code:

```
if (A equals B)
    result = A * -1
else
    result = A + B
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is absolutely possible and this what todays CPUs are using. The so called [logic gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate).
Of course depending on your project but won't probably need Intel processor to redo your work but much simpler components doing just that. See the above link for example components doing it.